# Solving an inequality $\frac{3}{x-1}\lt -\frac 2x$

Tags: inequality

I've picked up my old book on Calculus, and going through the introductory examples of the preliminaries, I fail to see my mistake for the following exercise:

> Solve the inequality $\frac 3{x-1} < -\frac2x$

In the walkthrough solution in the book, there's a note that we would like to multiply by $x(x-1)$ to clear the fractions in the inequality, but that would require us to consider three cases separately, so instead they transpose and combine the two fractions into a single one:

$$
\frac3{x-1}<-\frac2x\\
\frac3{x-1}+\frac2x<0\\
\frac{5x-2}{x(x-1)}<0
$$

Then goes on to solve the inequality based on the fact that they look for when the numerator and denominator have opposite signs. That is:

**CASE I**

$5x-2>0$ and $x(x-1)<0$ which gives the interval $\left(\frac25,1\right)$.

**CASE II**

$5x-2<0$ and $x(x-1) >0$ which gives the interval $(-\infty, 0)$

The solution set is then the union of the two intervals: $$(-\infty,0)\cup\left(\frac25,1\right)$$

**Question**

I first made an attempt solving this without looking at the walkthrough, and multiplied by $x$ (considering two cases, one for $x<0$ and the other for $x>0$) followed by adding $2$:

**CASE I** $x<0$

$$
\frac3{x-1}<-\frac2x\\
\frac{3x}{x-1}+2>0\\
5x-2>0\\
x>\frac25
$$

Not a solution as there is no interval for $x>\frac25$ when $x<0$

**CASE I** $x>0$

$$
\frac3{x-1}<-\frac2x\\
\frac{3x}{x-1}+2<0\\
5x-2<0\\
x<\frac25
$$

Gives the interval $(0,\frac25)$.

Well, it is clear I've done something wrong here, but I fail to understand what it is.

I (thought I) was using the rules
$$
a < b \,\text{and}\, c > 0 \;\rightarrow\; ac < bc\\
a < b \,\text{and}\, c < 0 \;\rightarrow\; ac > bc
$$

Comment: Error occurs when transposing x - 1 to the RHS without considering the sign of x - 1.

Comment: Think that after multiplying by $x$, you also move all terms to the same member. So your solution is similar to theirs, but it is more "heterogenous" and error prone.

Comment: Multiply both sides of the inequality by the positive number $x^2(x-1)^2$...

Comment: @JpMcCarthy interesting.. but I don't find that easier.. I got to $5x^3-7x^2+2x<0$, if that is even correct, and are not sure how to go from there..

Comment: @Kaos You should get $3(x-1)x^2<-2(x-1)^2x\Rightarrow 3(x-1)x^2+2(x-1)^2x<0\Rightarrow x(x-1)[3x+2(x-1)]<0$... note that you have a $+x^3$ with three real roots... the geometry must be like ~ (why) and so must be negative before the first root and in between the second roots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x\lt 0$, then we have $x-1\lt -1\lt 0$.

So, multiplying the both sides of 
$$\frac{3x}{x-1}+2\gt 0$$
by $x-1\lt 0$ gives
$$3x+2(x-1)\color{red}{\lt }0.$$

If $x\gt 0$, then we have $x-1\gt -1$. So, note that the sign of $x-1$ is not determined.

Comment: .. just noting that for $x>0$, the sign of $x-1$ needs to be evaluated separately for the cases $x<1$ and $x>1$ to get the final result.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{5x-2}{x(x-1)}<0 \Leftrightarrow (5x-2)x(x-1)<0$$
Let $f(x)=(5x-2)x(x-1)$

[image]

$$f(x)<0 \Leftrightarrow x \in (-\infty;0) \cup (\frac25;1)$$

Answer (score 1):

In your solution, from the step
$ \frac{3x}{x-1} + 2 < 0 $ to $ 5x-2<0 $, you missed the denominator.

Hence, the real inequality for that case is
$$\frac{5x-2}{x-1} < 0$$ which is the same as in their solution.

Comment: Thank you. However, I'm not sure if you have a typo, or have misread.. but their case has an additional $x$ in the denominator.. $\frac{5x-2}{x(x-1)}<0$

Comment: @Kaos You've already seperated the case according as $x>0$ or $x<0$

Answer (score 1):

By direct case analysis,

$$\frac3{x-1}<-\frac2x$$

- for $x<0$, the inequality is obviously true ($-<+$).
- for $1<x$, the inequality is obviously false ($+\not \lt-$).
- for $0<x<1$, you can multiply by $-(x-1)x$, yielding $-3x<2(x-1)$ or $5x>2$.

Hence

$$(-\infty,0)\cup\left(\frac25,1\right).$$

I guess that this is a more economical solution.